# How can I mitigate copper naphthenate (copper green) smell indoors?

Tags: pest-control, smell, odors, chemicals

Our contractor treated the edge of some plywood and the bottom of some studs with copper naphthenate. The goal was to treat yummy wood at the concrete interface, which is a good thing since termites love our house.

**But the smell!**

I can't stand it, especially in the small one stall bathroom.  Various other people who have walked into the space have noticed and commented on the smell... and right now the area is perpetually open and has been for weeks.

And I know the smell lasts forever. Yet here the wood in question will mostly be covered by drywall.  Is there anything can I do to mitigate the copper green smell? Has anyone else been successful in containing such a smell?

---

The product was:
Cuprolignum Standard Green No. 300, by Rudd Paint & Varnish Company

- Copper naphthenate 34.5%
- Chloroorthophenylphenol 2.5%
- Petroleum Solvent 63%

Slogan ***"Where there is Cuprolignum there is no rot"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using metal HVAC tape.  It worked very well.  I also tried spray plastic on some areas unsuitable for the tape and it worked.  The airtight seals keep in the copper smell, and the room instantly became more livable.

Answer (score 1):

A thick four coats of floor paint that is meant to be impermeable to damp and impervious to floor traffic helped seal in this stuff where someone used it to treat a bathroom stall against rot.

Yes, the stuff just smells horrible. It's essentially copper contaminated moth balls with a little extra phenol for sniffy goodness and not for interior use at all.

Answer (score 1):

I used 1 coat of Bulls Eye 123 primer then 2 coats of AFM Hard Seal (buy online) to mask the horrible/ toxic odor.